# What kind of object db._collections() return ArangoDB?

Tags: javascript, arangodb, foxx

In Foxx context, I am using the database methods to access all collections in arango `db._collections()`. The return value is an array. But within the array, each "object" is not a string, not an array, not an object.What is their type?

Example return:

```
//This is 1 array. Correct
[ 
 //Each should be an array but they are not.
  [ArangoCollection 41, "_analyzers" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 38, "_appbundles" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 31, "_apps" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 14, "_aqlfunctions" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 4, "_graphs" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 20, "_jobs" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 17, "_queues" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 67, "_statistics" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 74, "_statistics15" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 60, "_statisticsRaw" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 7, "_users" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 95, "animals" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 89, "demo" (type document, status loaded)], 
  [ArangoCollection 73882, "example" (type document, status loaded)] 
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db._collections()` returns an array of `ArangoCollection` objects.
You can find out about this type of object by running standard JavaScript inspection methods such as `Object.keys(...)` on it, e.g.

```
obj = db._collections()[0]; 
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) { 
  require("console").log(key + ' (' + typeof obj[key] + ')'); 
});
```